# Random images on specified divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, grid-layout

[image]

My requirement: I have 3 set of images- Large images, Vertical images, Rectangle images. When page is refreshed, In the shown layout, I want to display random image of the same set.

My problem is, only first large,vertical,rect angle div is displaying image randomly on every refresh. The other all images are showing the same as previous.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="largebox">            
  <a href="">             
    <img id="largeimg" src="" class="largeimage">
  </a>          
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
  <script language="javascript">
      // random number between 1 and 100
      var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
      document.getElementById("largeimg").src = "img/IMG_"+numRand+".jpg";
    </script>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Also, where is the php part?

Comment: You need to wrap your script within a loop.

Comment: You need to change the img src for all of those 12 <img> You cand do that by giving them similar id's like largeimg1...12, and acces them in a for loop in the scripting part.

Comment: @The Javatar images are coming from database. So, it is not possible to assign id value in html.

Comment: @VamsiAbbineni use the `.append()` within a foreach image, and add the `HTML` http://api.jquery.com/append/ and your `largebox` div could have an ID to append to.

Comment: Well then you can take the <img> by class with jquery foreach. $( ".largeimage" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).src = "...";
});

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

assuming you want unique images to be displayed, calling

```
var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
```

inside the loop may yield repeat values, hence the suggestion of creating a random value array first

```
----
```

I instantly thought of how this might work, you'd need an array with random values (1-100), and an array with the image elements, and you'd loop though the arrays and assign the random array value to the image element

so on page load create an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 100] (with a loop)
and the array of image elements

then shuffle the values with [shuffle javascript array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

take a = array with random numbers

take b = array with image elements (document.getElementsByClassName("largeimage"))

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

b[i].src = "img/IMG_"+a[i]+".jpg";

}
```

i hope it helps, i did not model and test this

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider your **HTML** to be

```
<div class="largebox">            
  <a href="">             
    <img id="largeimg1" src="" class="largeimage">
  </a>          
</div>

<div class="largebox">            
  <a href="">             
    <img id="largeimg2" src="" class="largeimage">
  </a>          
</div>
```

Then your **JS** code should look like

```
var count = $('.largebox').length;

for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
    var src1 = "img/IMG_"+numRand+".jpg";
    $('#largeimg'+i).attr("src", src1);
}
```

This is considering classes `largebox`, `largeimage` and ids `largeimg1`, `largeimg2` are to be used only for  Large images.

You can follow similar procedure for  Vertical images and Rectangle images.

Hope that helps you!